# How do i find array length inside an another array

Tags: javascript

I have following data.
How do i can find count/length of `permission` array.

```
Students= 

    [
        {
            Name:'Andy', 
            permission:
            [
                {'8778'},
                {'678'},
                {'89898'}
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
Students[0].permission.length
```

But when there are more students you should iterate to get the length:

```
for( var i = 0; i < Students.length; i++ ) {
  Students[i].permission.length;
}
```

Comment: ooops i missed simple adding [0] index... my mistake it is so simple

Answer (score 0):

```
Students[0].permission.length
```

Simple huhhh